# Editar registro creando un nuevo item a la tabla relacionada

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

Buen dia comunidad, alguien me puede dar una mano con este problema?. Necesito editar un registro agregandole un item a la tabla relacionada mediante ese select solo me agrega el idPersona y no el porcentaje. Gracias de antemano
Como puedo pasarle el valor porcentaje porque con $request dice que variable indefinida 
CONTROLLER

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $empresaconsorcio=EmpresaConsorcios::findOrFail($id);
    $empresaconsorcio -> nombre1=$request->nombre1;
    $empresaconsorcio -> id_actividadesCiiu=$request->id_actividadesCiiu;
    $empresaconsorcio -> ciudad_id=$request->ciudad_id;
    $empresaconsorcio -> idDepartamento=$request->idDepartamento;
    $empresaconsorcio -> descritores_id=$request->descritores_id;
    $empresaconsorcio -> entidadBancaria_id=$request->entidadBancaria_id;
    $empresaconsorcio -> save();
    $collection = collect([
        [
            $request->get('persona_id'),
            $request->get('porcentaje'),
        ],
    ]);
    $consorcios=collect($collection)->map(function ($con){
            foreach($con as $key => $value) {
                $con->consorcios()->create([
                    'persona_id' => $value->persona_id[$key],
                    'porcentaje' => $value->porcentaje[$key],
                ]);
            }
        });
        $empresaconsorcio->consorcios()->saveMany($consorcios);

    Session::flash('message', 'El registro se edito con exito');
    return redirect()->route('consorciados.index');

}
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el código como texto, no como imagen.

Comment: Tenés agregado `porcentaje` como [fillable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment)?